# EJB JMS Timer, any sample?

Tags: jms

I am using Spring on Tomcat. I want to use JMS Timer. Is there any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't support JMS. You need to use something like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).

For scheduling (timers) you can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

[Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls2/) has examples both for JMS and Quartz.

Comment: Quartz is good for me. Yes, Tomcat does not support JMS I know. But with the power of Spring Framework You can easily implement JMS on Tomcat and I have done it. It works perfectly.